# cakephp 1.1 - using a model in another model only by instantiating

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I need to use the methods in some other models in another one. I noticed that version 1.1 doesn't have `ClassRegistry` and I heard that I should use the `loadModel` method and everything worked fine. However I noticed that if I don't use this method, it will still work.

So the question is:

**1)** Is the following code correct or should I have done something different?

**2)** Does this have a major performance/speed drawback?

```
$something_model = new Something();
$something_model->findByEmail('test@test.com');
```

Comment: "should I have done something different" You should have upgraded to at least 1.3 stable - IMHO. Seriously, you cannot talk about performance or "best practice" regarding a working piece with of code with a totally outdated and dead framework version. For all new versions of Cake this would actually be a drawback - and you should use loadModel() or at least ClassRegistry::init('ModelName') - and never `new ModelName()`.

Comment: @mark I totally agree, however this is what we've been using in our team and I can't do much about it.

Comment: @mark How about 1.1? Should I use loadModel? or would the current code suffice?

Comment: Why not use relations instead of loading a new model?